# Mysql fetch data from similar but not related tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, union, fetch

I have product tables in my database like below:

```
shop1_products
shop2_products
shop3_products
.....
....
...
shop100_products
```

I want to show products from all tables on site tried with `union` but I think not ok with 100 tables.

I know that If we do it by making one products table with shopid column in it will make it simple. But in my website
logic  is different I  can't do that because this structure as it will force me to do double work on other modules.

I am thinking to do this with stored procedure but am new for `stored procedure`.

What do you think, how we can do this with efficient way ?

if `stored procedure` is best to do this then please provide me a sample code or reference link

Comment: Why does `UNION` not work?  In what way do the tables' schema differ?

Comment: schema is same but it will make slow when no of tables will grow like 100.. 200.... Union wil make it slow

Comment: how many columns do u need from all the tables here? is it just productname or something else?

Comment: @AnandPhadke: yes product name ,id,category... max 5-7 columns

Comment: Well, yes.  It's slow because you're trying to select from 100 tables and materialise a combined result... whatever you do will suffer in that way, as it's the nature of your problem.  If you want to fetch all of the products without selecting from 100 tables, you will need to restructure your database.

Comment: @ eggyal : Thanks... but, That I can't do . What do u think about stored procedures ?

Comment: As I said: whatever you do you will need to fetch from 100 tables and materialise a result, which will suffer the same performance issues as `UNION`.  This includes stored procedures.

Comment: @ eggyal:but stored  procedures are pre compiled.. That does'nt make sense here?

Comment: Okay, so you'd save on parsing the statement - but that cost is insignificant relative to the table operations.  I'd highly recommend benchmarking any alternative against the `UNION` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do like this put all the table names in a temp table then follow these steps in while loop.
Then create a table results with all the required columns

for each @tablename
insert into results
select product name ,id,category... from @tablename
repeat

Then finally select distinct * from results
```

---------------------------------CODE-----------------------------------------------------

```
create table temp(id int auto_increment primary key,tblname varchar(100));

insert into temp(tblname)
VALUES('shop1_products'),('shop2_products'),('shop3_products')...('shop100_products');


select min(id),max(id) into @vmin,@vmax from temp;
select @vmin,@vmax;

create table results(productname varchar(100),id int,category varchar(100)...);

while(@vmin <= @vmax)
Do
select tblname into @tablename from temp;

INSERT INTO results(product name ,id,category...)
select product name ,id,category... from @tablename

SET @vmin=@vmin+1;

END WHILE;

select distinct  * from results;
```

Comment: its not syntax i just gave you the prototype of the process

Comment: @ AnandPhadke: Can u please provide me it with exact syntax. As I said I am newbie for stored procedures

Comment: thank you very much. Will do changes in it as required and will comment if further help required